# Toggle styles for FAQ questions

Tags: jquery, styles, toggle

I am currently working on my website and haven't had much problem learning/figuring out the HTML and CSS.  Though I have a problem with my FAQ page using jQuery.  I want to toggle the style of my questions from open to closed.  Though no matter where I try and put the toggles it only changes the style when it is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('dd').hide()
    $('dt').click(function () {
        var par = $(this).next();
        $('dd').each(function () {
            if ($(this) !== par) {
                $(this).hide(1000);
            }
        });
        if (par.is(':visible')) {
            par.hide(1000);
        } else {
            par.show(1000);
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS (It might be a little redundant since I'm learning though posts/other websites):

```css
dl.faq dt    {
       color: #268bd2;
       font-weight: bold;
       cursor: pointer;
       margin: 0 0 10px 0;
       padding: 0 0 10px 20px;
       background: url(images/faqarrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
       line-height: 16px;
       border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
       }
dl.faq dd{
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
        padding: 0 0 10px 20px;
        background-color:#ededed;
        }
dl.faq dt:hover    {
       color: #2aa198;
       background-position: 0 -32px;
       background: url(images/faqarrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
       }
dl.faq dt.close{
       color: #268bd2;
       background-position: 0 -32px;
       background: url(images/faqarrow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
       }
dl.faq dt.open{
       color: #2aa198;
       background-position: 0 -32px;
       background: url(images/faqarrowdown.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
       }
dl.faq dt.open:hover {
        background-position: 0 -96px;
        background: url(images/faqarrowdown.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        }
```

Currently the .open style works but it wont go back to the closed one when another question is clicked.  I would love to figure this out!

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a jsFiddle.net example.

Comment: Completely forgot about jsFiddle.net will use it for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your desired action, we have a couple ways to perform this tasks. In my example I'm going to simply use a `<div>` that will open and close. Both of these will rely on you having all the elements already closed, either through a class name, or by default styling.

First method, if the opening and closing is not dependent on the other elements, you can simply toggle the open class.

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open'); 
};
```

Second method, for use if opening on item should close the others.

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open'); 
};
```

Either method will take care of your issue and should be easier to maintain than the method your currently implementing.

Comment: Cheers the second one works like a charm! I just had to add a .removeClass to the if (par.is(':visible')).  To get the class to be removed if you click on the same question.  
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
if (par.is(':visible')) {
  par.hide(1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('close');
} else {
  par.show(1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
}
[...]
```

Comment: You should clarify this a bit.